# Ansible time out on Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have been trying to use my YML file on the Vagrant box I built, which is CentOS. However, I am running into this timeout at ALL times:

```
ryan@ryan-Galago-UltraPro:~/Desktop/vagrant$ vagrant provision
[default] Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [Show off some basic Ansible features] *********************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<10.0.x.x> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<10.0.x.x> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<10.0.x.x> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/ryan/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=2222', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/home/ryan/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=vagrant', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.0.x.x', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441243799.45-82681900071220 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1441243799.45-82681900071220'"]
fatal: [default] => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ryan/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/ryan/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.0.x.x-2222-vagrant" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.x.x [10.0.x.x] port 2222.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 10.0.x.x port 2222: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.x.x port 2222: Connection timed out


TASK: [common | Install postgres] ********************************************* 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/ryan/site.retry

default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

I have looked all over the Internet to figure out why it keeps Timing out and came up nothing, so I am asking StackOverFlow for any type of suggestions. Here is what my VagrantFile looks like:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "cento"

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.groups = {
                "vagrant" => ["10.0.x.x"]
        }
        ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_ssh_user: "vagrant" }
        ansible.sudo = true
        ansible.verbose = "vvvv"
        ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
        ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"
  end
end
```

And my host file I am using:

```
[vagrant]
default ansible_ssh_host=10.0.x.x ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

Does anyone have any reason why when I run `vagrant provision`, it times out on me?

Update:
I have tried just using the default vagrant host file:

```
 Generated by Vagrant

default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

Is there a way to change the default ansible_ssh_host from the loopback address to it's actual IP?

Comment: What happens if you connect to 10.0.x.x with ansible_ssh_port=22, instead of 2222? When Vagrant configures the loopback address it sets up port forwarding, but that's only set on 127.0.0.1, not on the real IP.

Comment: It still times out. I tried connecting with port 22 and 2222

Comment: Hmm. The next thing to narrow down, then, is if it's an issue with the VM not listening to the incoming connection, or if it's that your credentials aren't working. 

Try opening an SSH connection to the host yourself, with `ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1 -vvv`, then compare the output of that with the other address.

Comment: Hmmm.. I tried it with the actual IP that's being used (not the loopback) and I get a no route to host, which is weird because the VM is up and has connectivity to the internet

Comment: Also if I go into the VM and ping the IP on my PC, i get No Route To Host... So quite possibly, the VM is not listening...

Comment: That sounds like your problem! What's the output of 'vagrant ssh-config'? And if you look with netstat, is there a virtual interface listening on the IP range the VM is in? (you'll see 'vboxnet' if you're using Virtualbox)

Comment: Well i actually figured out what was happening. I had to add an entry into my ~/.ssh/config file that points to the vagrant PPK and I had to make some adjustments to my host file.

Comment: @nikobella, thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Nice :) glad you got it!

Comment: Thanks me too!, It's especially helpful for other users that run into this particular issue since there is no other question like this one on the Internet (atleast none that i found!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what the problem was. Here are a few things I needed to do:

1. List an Entry to the loopback address in my ~/.ssh/config file which will point to Vagrant's insecure_private_key. Once I did that, I was able to SSH using Port 22 and 2222 (without using vagrant ssh command). In this case, I named the Host: VagrantVM.
2. Next thing was I needed to adjust the host file I was using to reference the ansible build:

   `[vagrant]
   VagrantVM ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_port=2222`

Once I made these adjustments, I ran `vagrant provision` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect to the newly-created box with `vagrant ssh` ?

What is your Ansible version? And are you using VirtualBox as the VM provider, or something else?

Maybe try, as described at http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html, to remove the `ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"` statement, as Vagrant should be generating its own Ansible dynamic inventory because you're using the `ansible.groups` statement.

Comment: If I remove it, it reads from the vagrant-generated hosts file and is unable to match the host. Is there a way to configure that vagrant generated host file to point to the correct IP rather than the loopback IP

Comment: Have a look in the `.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory` file to see what Vagrant has generated, then post it here.